# How to setup GoogleCredentials for BigQuery Authentication using service_account.json file in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am trying to set up `GoogleCredentials` with BigQuery into android but setting up the credential using _service_account.json_ is not working.

It throws **FileNotFoundException** error while fetching the service_account.json file, When I try to load the file with *InputStream* the same error occurs.

**This is my code**

```
GoogleCredentials credentials;
File credentialsPath = new File("service_account.json");
try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
} // Instantiate a client.

BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

Note: I have place **service_account.json** under *app/assets* folder

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56147202/1031958

Comment: @TamirKlein I want to set up into android, So I need a reference for Android only

Comment: Please provide your code exampls

Comment: GoogleCredentials credentials;
File credentialsPath = new File("service_account.json");  
try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath)) {
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
}
// Instantiate a client.
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

I have place service_account.json under app/assets folder

Comment: Hi Saumil, could you please edit your question adding the commented code, so it will be more helpful for the upcoming readers. Thanks :)

Comment: Looking at BigQuery [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#bigquery_client_json_credentials-java):   `File credentialsPath = new File("service_account.json");  // TODO: **update to your key path.**`. Why you are not using the correct path to the file /app/assets/service_account.json?

Comment: I have fixed the issue, Thanks :)